# Should I apply Kruskal Wallis test?

Tags: categorical-data, ordinal-data, likert, kruskal-wallis-test, social-network

I am doing research about the purchasing behaviour of the population.
Therefore, on my online survey, I have questions about the effect of the advertisement on social media on behaviour. So, the answers are 5 point Likert scale answers. And I have only one group - the general population. So, can I apply the Kruskal Wallis test to test the relationship between social media advertisement and purchasing behaviour?

Comment: How would you apply it if you only have one group?

Comment: Did you give the survey to subjects before and after they were exposed to the social media ad? If so, you might use a nonparametric Wilcoxon signed rank test to see if After - Before differences in responses had median $0.$ // In any case, please give score(s) you have for a few representative subjects and say exactly what you want to test.